# Translate numpy digitize function into go

Tags: go

Digitize function return the indices of the bins to which each value in input array belongs.

Below code is from python -

```py
x = np.array([0.8, 6.9, 3.5, 1.9])
bins = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.5, 4.0, 10.0])
inds = np.digitize(x, bins)
print(inds)
array([1, 4, 3, 2])
```

Answer (score 2):

This does it:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "sort"
)

func digitize(x, bins []float64) []int {
   inds := make([]int, len(x))
   for k, v := range x {
      inds[k] = sort.SearchFloat64s(bins, v)
   }
   return inds
}

func main() {
   x := []float64{0.8, 6.9, 3.5, 1.9}
   bins := []float64{0, 1, 2.5, 4, 10}
   inds := digitize(x, bins)
   fmt.Println(inds) // [1 4 3 2]
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/sort#SearchFloat64s

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type arr []float64

func (a arr) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return a[i] < a[j]
}

func (in arr) digitize(bins arr) ([]int, error) {
    if !sort.SliceIsSorted(bins, bins.Less) {
        return nil, errors.New("bins array is not sorted")
    }

    indices := make([]int, len(in))
    for i, x := range in {
        indices[i] = sort.SearchFloat64s(bins, x)
    }

    return indices, nil
}

func main() {
    var (
        x    = arr{0.8, 6.9, 3.5, 1.9}
        bins = arr{0.0, 1.0, 2.5, 4.0, 10.0}
    )

    indices, err := x.digitize(bins)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(indices)
}
```

Ref: https://golang.org/pkg/sort#SearchFloat64s

> SearchFloat64s searches for x in a sorted slice of float64s and returns the index as specified by Search. The return value is the index to insert x if x is not present (it could be len(a)). The slice must be sorted in ascending order.